# Copy Sales Order Data to OrderKey

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here is my test bunny sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/151h1XjB98NOBnO0otNaql3ASjK84CccZZ399dX4BMBM/edit?usp=sharing

What I am trying to accomplish:

1. User inputs sales order on the 'salesOrder' Sheet
2. User submits sales order
3. a) sales order info is written to 'OrderKey' Sheet
   b) the header info (Date, Company, Purchase Order, Sales Order,  Contact, email, phone, comments, ship via, account ) is repeated for every Product Line Item entered into the sheet into the 'OrderKey' Sheet

Having troubles figuring out how to go about doing this.

I have now created a 'kludge' sheet to formulaically copy over live information from the 'salesOrder' Sheet.

I named it kludge because It is not an elegant way of solving my problem, and not as I would be hoping to solve it.

At any rate, the 'kludge' method is not working due to appending NULL DATA... so how do I copy over only not null data?

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Submit Sales Order', 'menuItem1')
      .addToUi();
}


function menuItem1() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("kludge");
  var sourceInfo = sheet.getRange("A:N65");
  var targetInfo = ss.getSheetByName("OrderKey");
  var values = sourceInfo.getValues();
  targetInfo.appendRow(values[0]);

  sheet.getRange('B4:B5').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('B8').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('G6:G8').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('F10:G10').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('A13:B76').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('J13:J76').clearContent();
  var cell = activeSheet.getRange("I1");
  var cellValue = cell.getValue();
  cell.setValue(cellValue + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quick solution for before(before kludge) version , not sure this is the best way,

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("salesOrder");

var val1 = sheet.getRange("G3").getValue();
var val2 = sheet.getRange("B5").getValue();
var val3 = sheet.getRange("G5:G8").getValues();
var val4 = sheet.getRange("B8").getValue();
var val5 = sheet.getRange("F10").getValue();
var val6 = sheet.getRange("G10").getValue();

var targetInfo = ss.getSheetByName("OrderKey");
targetInfo .appendRow([val1,val2,val3[0][0],val3[1][0],val3[2][0],val3[3][0],val4,val5,val6]);

sheet.getRange('B4:B5').clearContent();
sheet.getRange('B8').clearContent();
sheet.getRange('G6:G8').clearContent();
sheet.getRange('F10:G10').clearContent();
sheet.getRange('A13:B76').clearContent();
sheet.getRange('J13:J76').clearContent();
var cell = activeSheet.getRange("I1");
var cellValue = cell.getValue();
cell.setValue(cellValue + 1);
```

Comment: Thank you, I did not know about the use of .appendRow how it worked... with different ranges.  I see this would copy to 1 Row of data for only the 'Header' Order data, and leave the Product range alone.  I am still trying to figure out how to merge the Product, Qty, range with multiple rows.

Comment: Hmmm so appendRow suggests only a 1D array.  How would I loop for every product line item entered?

Comment: Welcome, you can [read more](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents)!
If so you question is too broad. narrow down to small segment and ask here. People will help you.

Comment: for that, you need to configure an `onEdit` trigger. [read this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Comment: I don't see how an onEdit trigger would help.  Sounds like it would make a mess of line item data if a user changes things before submission.

Comment: yes, you have to check editing cell and if it is correct one, enter product line. or else you can add a save button. for that, Go into "Insert > Drawing...", Draw a button and add it to the spreadsheet. Then click it and click "assign Macro...", then insert the name of the function you wish to execute there.

Comment: I need to stay away from any drawings added to the sheet.  images outside of the print area mess up the export to print.  I originally had a couple of buttons set just out of the print area, but it completely messed up export to PDF, which is why I am trying to roll this into a menu item.   That being said, do you understand the problem I am trying to solve, is there anyway I can help better explain it?  I am not a seasoned programmer as you can tell, any help would be really appreciative.

Comment: Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

Aurielle Perlmann has elegantly found a solution HERE:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34982276/5229520

Thank you.